# Any reasonable source to RTSP stream

Tags: c#, stream, rtsp

I have to take output of this [card](https://www.magewell.com/products/pro-capture-dual-sdi) which is not easy (but I will eventually figure it out) and I have to stream it as RTSP stream in local network.

So my question is is there any sane piece of code, library or software that will take some kind of input and make it available as RTSP stream? I need to be able to control it from my C# program. **RTSP is must**.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/27007456/7357322

Comment: Try VLC (videolan.org)

Comment: Even receiving RTSP stream directly from camera with VLC nuget for C# gave 3s delay. I hope anything from the thread Andrii posted will work.

Comment: The time costs that u spend for coding this is bigger then just buy encoder for sdi that Supports rtsp or onvif. The costs around 1300$ just for u as Information :)

Comment: Here you are wrong. FFmpeg with simple-rtsp-server do the job and can be run just by executing .exe. It's free.

Comment: And it detects this GPU as input as needed.